# Accessing docker ports from browser localhost:8000 doesn't work

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gulp

I was following a tutorial serving content for a simple app using `gulp`, and managed to get it working on my local (Mac) machine, which allowed me to access the site from localhost:8000 in my browser. However, when I tried to dockerize it with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17.2-stretch-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm i npm@latest -g && npm install -g gulp
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
CMD ["gulp", "serve", "--dir=folder"]
EXPOSE 8000
```

After building the docker image and running it with:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 test-image
```

It looked like it was successfully started with the same console output I get when I was running it locally:

```
[08:55:46] Using gulpfile /app/gulpfile.js
[08:55:46] Starting 'serve'...
[08:55:46] Starting 'build'...
...
[08:55:53] Finished 'build' after 6.99 s
[08:55:53] Starting 'watch'...
[08:55:53] Starting '<anonymous>'...
[08:55:53] Starting 'watch:css'...
[08:55:53] Starting 'watch:html'...
[08:55:53] Starting 'watch:images'...
[08:55:53] Starting 'watch:js'...
[08:55:53] Webserver started at http://localhost:8000
[08:55:54] Finished '<anonymous>' after 52 ms
```

Also verified that there were no errors with running docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
f4c92aaf3a8a   test-image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   practical_borg
```

But when I tried to access localhost:8000 from my browser, I ran into `localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`
I also tried `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 test-image` with the same result - not sure if I'm doing something wrongly, my understanding is that with docker on Mac, I should be able to access it from my localhost:8000 as long as the port is mapped correctly..

Comment: You should add, in an [edit] of your question, what `docker ps -a` gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Use 0.0.0.0 as gulp host address, it will serve on all interfaces, and you should be able to reach it.

It didn't work so far because the localhost address (127.0.0.1) isn't the same between your host network and the container network.